# Call to undefined function wp_get_sites()

Tags: multisite

In my plugin, in `init` action I use `get_sites()` function... however it throws:

`Call to undefined function get_sites() in XYZ on line 154`
whats solution?

p.s.
 1) The same happens with `wp_get_sites()`...
 2) no help when I use `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/ms-blogs.php');` 
3) I use wordpress version 4.6

Comment: What version of WordPress is being used? Where is `get_sites()` being called (which hook)?

Comment: in `init` as i said ( version 4.6).   I doubt problem is that the function is called within non MULTI-SITE site....

Answer (score 1):

Solution seems to be:

```
if(function_exists('get_sites'))         {$sites= get_sites();} 
elseif(function_exists('wp_get_sites'))  {$sites= wp_get_sites();}
```

Comment: This will not work properly, as the deprecated function still exists in WP 4.6+. Better to test for the WP version (also see my answer below).

Comment: If the deprecated function still exists, then it's usable. When it is not available any more, then it will stop working and the alternative will be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The wp_get_sites function was deprecated in WP 4.6. The full answer is the first answer here: [Sorting list of sites from multisite network using wp_get_sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231114/sorting-list-of-sites-from-multisite-network-using-wp-get-sites/231121) .

Also, the function provided by Lance Cleveland (in the answers in the above link) provides a test for the proper function to use. But it is incomplete, as the old function is deprecated so the old function still exists if pre-4.6. The test should look for the WP version, not the existence of the function. (See my answer to the same question.)

I have a plugin for multisites that looped through the sites. The pre-4.6 code was causing problems on 4.6+ site, so changed the plugin's requirements to require WP 4.6 or later. The plugin automatically deactivates with a message if pre-4.6 is found.

That said, keeping WP updated is strongly recommended. There are security risks (and compatibility issues) with not doing updates.

Comment: Testing for the version is generally the wrong way to go about detecting which function to use. A simple search on the web will show that the concept of object detection is superior over version detection for many different frameworks, programming languages, and implementations. Proven [many](https://johnresig.com/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/) [times](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/not_browser_detect.html) [over](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/not_browser_detect.html).

Comment: But I didn't recommend checking the version of the browser or JS, as your links discuss. I said to check the WP version, which will tell you which method to use. Checking for the existence of the function will not fully work in all instances, as the function will still be there in 4.6+, but won't work right. So checking for the WP version is the best way, IMHO.

Comment: Again, I was referring to the concept not the languages or the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_sites()` function (replacing the `wp_get_sites()` function, [deprecated](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sites/)) only works in a context of a *network of sites*.

You can create a network by using the *multisite* feature, following [those instructions in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).